# Probability question with no number

Tags: word-problem

I Ama trying to solve this probability question but it does not indicate the total amount of socks in the drawer so I am not sure how to go about solving it.

Peter has many socks, all the same except that they are in five different colours. He is leaving to catch and early train and does not want to wake his wife (great guy) so he packs in the dark. He needs seven pairs of socks, each sock in each pair the same colour. Hoe many socks must he take to be sure of achieving this?

Comment: If he has to be sure this is no probability question, as announced in the title.

Comment: sorry I'm not a super formal mathematician

Comment: Hint: Try to work out the answers to simpler questions and look for a pattern in your thinking. Why would the answer be $3$ if there were just two colors and he needed just one matching pair? Then gradually increase the number of colors and the number of pairs needed.

Answer (score 0):

He needs $7\cdot2=14$ socks that can be paired off. Now find out for each number $n\geq14$ how many "odd socks" could be  among $n$ drawn socks at worst, until you find an $n$ that guarantees $7$ perfect pairs.

E.g., if he draws $n=15$ socks there could be $1$, $3$, or $5$ "odd socks" in the lot, so that in the worst case he would have picked only $5$ perfect pairs.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not follow could you elaborate a bit sorry.